# Excel: Check Sheet Dependencies within a Workbook?

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I'm in the process of refactoring a huge workbook woth a lot of legacy parts, redundant computations, cross-dependencies etc.

Basically, I'm trying to remove unneeded sheets and implement some proper information flow within the workbook. Is there a good way to extract the dependencies between the sheets (with VBA)?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: As in ? http://superuser.com/questions/234124/excel-dataflow-uml-viewer-navigator-visualiser-tool-hint

Comment: Trace Precedents only shows the precedents of a single cell. What I'm looking for is something like what the Links menu does for inter-workboot links, but for worksheets within a workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a little sub to do this. It moves all the sheets into seperate workbooks and prints out the dependencies. The advantage over using `showPrecedents` is that it captures all links including names, embedded forms/diagramms etc.

Word of warning: Moving worksheets isn't undo-able, save your workbook before running this and close (without saving) and re-open afterwards.

```
Sub printDependencies()
    ' Changes workbook structure - save before running this
    Dim wbs As VBA.Collection, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheets
    Dim i As Integer, s As String, wc As Integer
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set wbs = New VBA.Collection
    wbs.Add ThisWorkbook, ThisWorkbook.FullName

    For i = ws.Count To 2 Step -1
        ws(i).Move
        wc = Application.Workbooks.Count
        wbs.Add Application.Workbooks(wc), Application.Workbooks(wc).FullName
    Next
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In wbs
        For Each s In wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
            Debug.Print wb.Worksheets(1).Name & "<-" & wbs(s).Worksheets(1).Name
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The code isn't very polished or user-friendly, but it works.

Comment: I have a Compile error my friend.

For Each control variable must be Variant or Object.
At 
<pre> For Each s In wb.LinkSources (xlExcelLinks) <code>

I hope you can help me with it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ShowPrecedents and NavigateArrow.
here is some pseudocode

```
for each oCell in oSht containing a formula
ocell.showprecedents
do until nomoreprecedents
i=i+1
Set oPrec = oCell.NavigateArrow(True, 1, i)
If not oPrec.Parent Is oSht Then
' off-sheet precedent
endif
loop
next ocell
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise there was actually a way to track off-sheet references. Superb.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps at "Find external references that are used in cells" topic of the following link:

[Find external references in a worbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-external-references-links-in-a-workbook-fcbf4576-3aab-4029-ba25-54313a532ff1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

But instead of enter the "[" you should enter the name of the sheet you're trying to find its dependencies. It will display a large list of every single cell referencing the sheet, but at the end it works. Haven't find the way to group by Sheet.